# ¿Cómo reemplazar valores en un txt?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy realizando el juego del **Ahorcado**, en el cual guardo nombre y puntaje del **Jugador** en un **txt**. Lo que necesito hacer es que si el mismo jugador vuelve a jugar, reemplazar el puntaje en la misma línea donde se guardó del **txt**, sin que se cree una nueva línea en el mismo, como en el ejemplo.

```
Jugador 1 1500
Jugador 1 500
Jugador 2 800
Jugador 2 400
```

**Escritura** del txt:

```
StreamWriter guardarPtos = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + (@"\Puntajes.txt", true));
{
    guardarPtos.WriteLine(stNombreJugador + " - " + inPuntos);
    guardarPtos.Close();
}
```

**Lectura** del txt:

```
private void frmPuntajes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader puntajes = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + (@"\Puntajes.txt"));
    string linea = puntajes.ReadLine();           
    do
    {
        lbxPuntajes.Items.Add(linea);
        linea = puntajes.ReadLine();
    } while (linea != null);
}
```

El nombre lo guardo en una clase **Jugador**:

```
public class clsNombreJugador
{
    private string _nombre;

    public string Nombre
    {
        get { return _nombre; }
        set { _nombre = value; }
    }
}
```

y los puntajes directamente en una variable, de acuerdo al nivel de dificultad seleccionado:

```
lblMensaje.Text = "¡Muy Bien! Acertaste ingresando la letra " + stLetra;                                       
if (rbFacil.Checked == true)
{
    inPuntos = inPuntos + 50; lblCantPun.Text = inPuntos.ToString();
}
else if (rbMedio.Checked == true)
{
    inPuntos = inPuntos + 150; lblCantPun.Text = inPuntos.ToString();
}
else
{
    inPuntos = inPuntos + 300; lblCantPun.Text = inPuntos.ToString();
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo lees el txt? ¿Cómo escribes en el txt? ¿Guardas los datos en una clase aparte? ¿Donde está tu trabajo?

Comment: Como bien dice @NaCl , tendrás que poner el código que tienes. Esta página está hecha para ayudar, no para hacer el trabajo.

Comment: se me hace que esta duplicada

Comment: Debes pensar como lo harías a mano. Lo normal sería abrir el .txt, ir leyendo linea a linea hasta encontrar el nombre del jugador cuya puntuación deseas actualizar, modificar la puntuacion y volver a guardarlo todo. Por cierto, te recomiendo que uses algun separador entre el nombre del jugador y la puntuacion para que te sea mas sencillo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es simple, lo primero que debes hacer cuando vayas a escribir la puntuación es leer el archivo entero y comprobar si existe ya un jugador con ese nombre con alguna puntuación:

```
    private void GuardarPuntos(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + (@"\Puntajes.txt");
                      for(i=0;i<lineas.Length;i++){
                       if(lineas[i].Substring(0,lineas[i].IndexOf(" - ")).Equals(stNombreJugador)){
                      lineas[i]=stNombreJugador + " - " + inPuntos;
                         }
                 } 

                    File.WriteAllLines(Application.StartupPath + (@"\Puntajes.txt"), lineas);
               }
```

Aquí lo que he hecho es comprobar si existe, si no existe lo escribes como ya lo estabas haciendo tú.

Comment: Esto no funcionaría dado el ejemplo del OP. `Jugador 1` y `Jugador 2` serían lo mismo ya que buscas el primer indice de `' '`. Por eso es importante como sugerí usar algun tipo de separador

Comment: Tienes razón, no había caído en que el nombre tiene un espacio @Pikoh. Lo que no me cuadra mucho es que según su código, el txt se separa mediante " - " aunque él no lo haya puesto así.

Comment: Tienes razón, yo no habia notado eso. Entonces puedes modificar tu respuesta haciendo un `Split('-')` o `IndexOf('-')`

Comment: Ya se que soy un poco pesado, pero ojo con el `IndexOf(' - ')`, no compilará. O bien pones `IndexOf('-')` o `IndexOf(" - ")`

Comment: @Pikoh ya lo siento, muchas gracias que a estas horas no rindo ya...

Comment: Nada hombre,eso nos pasa a todos. Buena respuesta.

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo tengo un problema con el código.. me tira el siguiente error en la sentencia `if(lineas[i].Substring(0,lineas[i].IndexOf(" - ")).Equals(stNombreJugador))` **la longitud no puede ser inferior a cero**. Te lo muestro asi pq no se como mostrarte con una imagen

Comment: @AguFortini no estoy seguro ahora mismo, pero puede ser porque no encuentre el string " - ". Creo que si no lo encuentra te devuelve -1

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo gracias por la información, me sirvió mucho. Ahora me gustaría ordenar los puntajes de manera ascendente, que idea me darías para hacerlo?